# Biblatex with biber backend results in undefined control sequences but not with bibtex backend

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use Texmaker (verion 3.4.1) and MikTeX 2.9 (which has been installed one week ago). Texmaker is configured to use biber: I replaced "bibtex %.aux" by "biber %". If I run LaTeX, then the file compiles without errors. The same goes for BiBTeX. But if I then run LaTeX again, then get error messages.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{label}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here are the error messages:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name
>
> l.39   \endentry
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name
>
> l.39   \endentry

There are no error messages if I replace `backend=biber` with `backend=bibtex`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This bug is fixed in the current development branch of `biblatex`. Install this branch to your local texmf tree and you can use `biblatex`. Here the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/

Comment: Before you install some development branch: Run the update manager of miktex. In case you have a multiuser setup: do it in user + admin mode. (biber + biblatex works fine for me with an up-to-date miktex).

Comment: I'm sorry about this, I accidentally uploaded a broken biblatex 2.1 to TL originally. This might have found it's way into MikTeX. The 2.1 on SourceForge and in TL now is correct.

Comment: i still have the same problem after running biber

Comment: Please do `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` and paste here the top ten lines of the file which this returns.