# How to define the bibliography style with 4 letters author, a gap and the two numbers of the year

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

How can I make the reference list as:
4 letters a gap and the two numbers of the year,

> [Taja 00a]  E.   Tajahuerce   and   B.   Javidi,   "Encrypting
>   three-dimensional  information  with  digital  holography,"  Appl. 
>   Opt.,  39,  6595-6601,  (2000).

where [Taja 00a] means the first four letter of the author's surname, a space, and the year (only two numbers).

Also, I would like to cite this reference as [Taja 00a].

I have been reading the `natbib` package and trying different things such as `\citep` or `\citealp`, and the `\setcitestyle` command. Nothing lucky so far.
Could anyone help me define this please?

This is a minimal example I am testing on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Thesis_References.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,names=1,lowercase]{labelname}
    }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
    }
}

\renewcommand{\labelalphaothers}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\padded{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{JavidiBOOK:2005}, \cite{Matoba:09}. \cite{Matoba:04, Unnikrishnan:06}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're ready to use the `biblatex` package, you might want to check out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105690/custom-biblatex-reference-style

Comment: Are you already using a bibliography style such as `alpha`? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks very much for your tips. I am testing the biblatex using alphaTemplate. Haven't got what I want yet. Please help.

Comment: @Shea: Which "alphaTemplate"? Can you provide a minimal working example with your current settings?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel How do I get the \printbibliography work. The reference list can not be shown.

Comment: @Shea: Did you run `pdflatex`->`biber`->`pdflatex`->`pdflatex`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I added Biber into the typesetting in TeXworks. I am using XeLaTeX, and I am guessing this wouldn't be a problem. The console gives me: Entity: line 1855: parser error : expected '>'
        <bcf:field>title</bcf
                             ^
Entity: line 1855: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: field line 0 and bcf
        <bcf:field>title</bcf
                             ^

Comment: I am trying to fix this biber problem first.

Comment: @Shea: First you should remove all auxiliary files. To simplify the compilation you can use the tool arara.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I successfully installed arara (which is really amazing), and used the following derectives: % arara: xelatex: { synctex: true }
% arara: makeindex: {  style: stylefile.ist }
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: { synctex: true }
% arara: xelatex: { synctex: true }                             and this error can not be solved: \abx@ffd@*@labelalpha #1->\padded 
                                  {#1}
l.56     \endentry

Comment: @Shea: The command `\padded` is undefined. That's the reason for the error. Remove the command and everything works fine.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks Marco. BTW, arara is very cool.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Just a small question, how do I put a space between the two labelelements, like [Taja 00a]

Comment: @Shea: Currently I can't test. I will answer later.

Comment: @Shea: You can do the following addition to `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`: Use: `\labelelement{\literal{~}}` The complete code is: `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,names=1,lowercase]{labelname}
    }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{~} 
    }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
    }
}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks for your reply. I was testing the \literal earlier and got this biber error that I cann't get through: like the same question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66459/biblatex-with-biber-backend-results-in-undefined-control-sequences-but-not-with       I use Texworks + MikTeX, and the biblatex is downloaded by MikTex automatically. Therefore I think the version of biblatex should be the latest.

Comment: @Shea: Sorry. I am using the development version of `biblatex` (version 2.5+) and biber (biber version: 1.6 (beta)). With the current version you should try `\literal{{ }}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It works! I'd better update to the new version of biblatex. Now I am going to define the entry format (volume, number, and etc.) to meet the requirements. Thanks a million for your time!!

Comment: @Shea: I think your original question has changed. Maybe you should ask a new question with your current biblatex settings and we can close this question.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes, the basic customized settings for my case can be found in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles  and if I run into some problems with this I will open a new question. Let's close this. Thanks again:-)