# Missing packages after upgrade?

Tags: biber

I am using LaTeX+Biber+Texmaker under Ubuntu. I have recently upgraded Ubuntu from 12.10 to 14.10, and I am having some issues with some of my LaTeX documents after that. I thought the issue might be due to missing LaTeX packages, therefore I installed also texlive-full (http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/texlive-full), which gathers all the tex packages in the Ubuntu repository. The error log returns a set of errors as follows:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Warning: File 'phd_drupal_cbpp_confirmation.bbl' is wrong form
at version - expected 2.4.
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'phd_drupal_cbpp_confirmation.bbl' found.
(./phd_drupal_cbpp_confirmation.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...refsection @entry@\blx@slist@scheme
l.41 \endentry
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...refsection @entry@\blx@slist@scheme
l.41 \endentry
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...refsection @entry@\blx@slist@scheme
l.61 \endentry
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...refsection @entry@\blx@slist@scheme
l.61 \endentry
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[...]
```

The preamble of the main document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{report}

%% Include options to break urls
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, urldate=long]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[top=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}

% Ordinals and numbering
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

%TO-DO: Check package dependencies
%\usepackage{siunitx}

%% Manual hyphenation
\hyphenation{fle-xi-bi-li-ty}
\hyphenation{qua-li-ty}
\hyphenation{em-pha-si-se}


%% Style
%% Paragraph settings
\setlength{\parskip}{0.9em}

% Checkmarks
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 


\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


[...]
```

The most similar issue I have found is [Biblatex with biber backend results in undefined control sequences but not with bibtex backend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66459/biblatex-with-biber-backend-results-in-undefined-control-sequences-but-not-with) , but I am not sure if it is related to the same problem.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try deleting your auxiliary files (particularly the `.bbl` file)? The warnings above suggest that the Biber/`biblatex` version has changed and your files therefore need updating.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JosephWright! That worked! The document compiles now. However, I am still having an issue while running biber from Texmaker (I am not sure if it is related to this):

Possible precedence issue with control flow operator at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 395.

Any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Looking at https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/biblatex-biber/ this last error seems to be due to another issue, so I will take a look at it in a separate one.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved after deleting the auxiliary files, as suggested by @Joseph Wright. It seems to be necessary after upgrading the version.